CSS Grid + Flex: info-container won't overflow on img
with grid and flex properties i'm trying to let my info-box overflow a bit over my image instead of having it right below. Is there any suggestions to make it possible?
So far I tried the simple techniques of grid. I made a whole container for both the img and info-box. Thereafter I wrapped my info-container as an grid to try to move it up so it could overflow my img.



.info-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 70ch) 1fr;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  >* {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  >img {
    grid-column: 2;
    max-block-size: 300px;
    inline-size: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0;
  gap: 1rem 2rem;
}

.info-box {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.info-item {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.info-item h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #ccc;
}

.info-item p {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.live-preview .btn {
  background-color: #f7b500;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.live-preview .btn:hover {
  background-color: #e0a400;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .info-box {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .info-item {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .live-preview {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}
<div class="info-container">
  <figure>
    <img src="./src/assets/images/case-study-photo2.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="info-box">
      <div class="info-item">
        <h4>Case Name</h4>
        <p>Taxes & Efficiency</p>
      </div>
      <div class="info-item">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <p>Business</p>
      </div>
      <div class="info-item">
        <h4>Date</h4>
        <p>27th September 2022</p>
      </div>
      <div class="info-item live-preview">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Live Preview</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




each element has its own box model and they don't overlap. That's not how overflow is intended. If you wish to overlap elements you need to use something like position: absolute or use a negative margin-top. By the way I see you have part of the info box impressed in the image itself.. they will never match! so just don't use that strategy

Try this:
.info-container {position: relative;}
.info-box {position: absolute; bottom: -30px;}
position: absolute: The .info-box is positioned absolutely inside the info-container. This allows it to float over the image.
bottom: -30px: This moves the info-box up, so it partially overlaps the image.
